# Show/Hide Navigation Component for certain routes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a main App level component like below

```
        <div className="app-container">
            <AppHeader />
            <div className="app-content">
                <Routes />
            </div>
            <Notification />
        </div>
```

I want the `<AppHeader />` to appear (or be hidden) for certain routes. How can this be done in a clean way in React? I am using React Router

Answer (score 1):

One way of going about it is to create a new `Switch` and not render anything for those paths you don't want to show your header in, and render the header for every other path.

**Example**

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" />
  <Route path="/about" />
  <Route path="/*" component={AppHeader} />
</Switch>
```